# ¿Adaptar banner a dispositivo móvil?

Tags: css, responsive

Tengo unos banners y en versión de pantalla normal se ven bien, pero en versión móvil la imagen no se aprecia bien, he intentado lo siguiente con css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .porto-ultimate-content-box-container {
        height: 250px;
        min-height: 250px;
    }   
}
```

Pero solo adapta el div mas no la imagen, el div tiene como background las imágenes, cualquier aporte o referencia se agradece.

Este es el link de la web:

https://tintasytecnologia.com/

Imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: para que las etiquetas sean responsivas a la pagina se suele poner esta eqtiqueta en el head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Hola, si lo que pasa es que es un template de wordpress y trabaja con unos complementos, pero no he logrado adaptarlo a móvil con css esos banners. Gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer y ya lo probe es

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .porto-ultimate-content-box-container {
        height: 250px;
        min-height: 250px;
    }
   .porto-ultimate-content-box-container > div {
        height: 100%!important;
        min-height: 100%!important;
    }  
}
```

o también lo podrías dejar que fuera general